# PHP usage easy for template's

Tags: php, templates

Actually i once saw some PHP code on php.net but i forgot its name or usage.
It is something may be related to heredoc (may be not)

What i am trying to achieve is to do HTML inside php IF conditions..

it was somthing like

xhtml code here

i hope u understand what i am trying to ask! 
thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry the code didnt post up! < ? php IF ? > xhtml < ? php ENDIF; ? >

Comment: are you looking for something like template toolkit (perl) for php?

Comment: you can wrap code in ``back ticks`` or use the code sample button on the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the alternative syntax for control structures, it's something like this:

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
<div>A is equal to 5</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: is it nicknamed "wordpress style", because it's initial extensive use was with wordpress?

Comment: @dimitris not sure what the nickname is - just know of it as the alternative syntax :)

Comment: may be it is realted to wordpress caz i also saw it the first time in wordpress templates. now i remember it ehhh! :-D

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

```
<?php 
/** Other PHP code */ 

$is = true;
?>

<?php ob_start(); ?>

    <h3>Caption</h3>

    <?php if($is): ?>

        ...some text 1

    <?php else: ?>

        ...some text 2

    <?php endif; ?>      

<?php $out = ob_get_clean(); ?>

<?php 
/** Other PHP code */

echo $out;  
?>
```